# Kivy: Binding a callback to SimpleListAdapter in kv

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to do something very similar to one of the Kivy Listview examples - I'm using Builder and kv to create a ListView and populate it with lines from a text file.  My problem is I can't figure out how to bind a callback so I can move the selected line's text over to a listbox.  My code:

```
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
#:import label kivy.uix.label
#:import sla kivy.adapters.simplelistadapter


<ListViewModal>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    ListView:
        id: listview_modal
        #on_selection_change: callback # <==== attempt #1
        size_hint: .8, .8
        adapter:
            sla.SimpleListAdapter(
            data=[s.strip() for s in open('/Users/zen/Dropbox/todo/todo.txt').readlines()],
            cls=label.Label,
            selection_mode='single',
            allow_empty_selection=True)
            #on_selection_change: callback # <===== attempt #2
""")

class ListViewModal(ModalView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListViewModal, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MainView(GridLayout):
    '''Implementation of a simple list view that reads data from a file.
    '''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['cols'] = 2
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.listview_modal = ListViewModal()
        self.add_widget(self.listview_modal)

        text_input = TextInput()
        self.add_widget(text_input)

    def callback(self, adapter):
        self.text_input.text = adapter.selection.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(MainView(width=800))
```

I've also tried various combinations of adding IDs and attributes to be able to get to the adapter in the MainView class, all to no avail.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is you are using `SimpleListAdapter` - it is 'simple' because it does not support selection. Use the regular `ListAdapter` instead. You also need to use `ListItemButton` to support selection. The `on_selection_change` event must be bound from Python, not kv, or else it won't work. Finally, you also had a couple issues with the `text_input` widget and trying to get `text` from `adapter.selection`, which is a list not a widget.

I've updated your code and annotated my changes with comments.

```
Builder.load_string("""
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#:import la kivy.adapters.listadapter


<ListViewModal>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400
    ListView:
        id: listview_modal
        size_hint: .8, .8
        adapter:
            la.ListAdapter(
            data=[s.strip() for s in open('/Users/zen/Dropbox/todo/todo.txt').readlines()],
            cls=ListItemButton,  ### use ListItemButton instead of Label
            selection_mode='single',
            allow_empty_selection=True)
""")

class ListViewModal(ModalView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListViewModal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ### Bind to `on_selection_change` here in `__init__`
        self.ids['listview_modal'].adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.callback)

    ### in `__init__`, we don't have a parent yet, so we proxy the callback
    def callback(self, adapter):
        return self.parent.callback(adapter)

class MainView(GridLayout):
    '''Implementation of a simple list view that reads data from a file.
    '''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['cols'] = 2
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.listview_modal = ListViewModal()
        self.add_widget(self.listview_modal)

        self.text_input = TextInput()  ### use `self.text_input` instead of `text_input`
        self.add_widget(self.text_input)

    def callback(self, adapter):
        self.text_input.text = adapter.selection[0].text  ### get `text` from the first selected item
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, shortly after posting this I decided to convert to ListAdapter and I got it working.  Thanx for the clarification.